# Query UUID Key using Linq + MongoDb Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, .net-core

I'm having a hard time querying a MongoDb collection by the _id key, all other keys works smoothly but the _id, I believe is something related to the way that Mongo stores de _id (as Binary). I have tried almost everything I found about mongo + C# GUIDs, a lot here in StackOverflow, but nothing seems to work.

Using MongoDb.Driver 2.11.5

Here is my document

```
_id:UUID('e68b2095-2d53-46a6-bca6-1e13f7bd2d26'),
DateCreated:2021-01-14T00:38:18.368+00:00,
IsActive:true,
Name:"The Witcher"
```

Entity

```
public class Game
{
    public Game(Guid id, string name, DateTime dateCreated, bool isActive)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        DateCreated = dateCreated;
        IsActive = isActive;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; private set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public bool IsActive { get; private set; } = true;

}
```

Repository class

Here is the problem, `dt` returns the Entity it should, but `dt2` is always null

```
public async Task GetById(Guid id)
{
    var dt = DbSet.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Name == "The Witcher").FirstOrDefault();
    var dt2 = DbSet.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Mapping class

```
public GameConfig()
{
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Game>(cm =>
    {
        cm.AutoMap();
        cm.MapIdMember(c => c.Id);
    });
}
```

Config apply (This is called by the startup class before the MongoDB connection is opened)

```
public class NoSqlEntitiesConfigurer
{
    public void Configure()
    {
        BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));
        new GameConfig();
        new SectionConfig();
    }
}
```

Comment: Verify what the `id` parameter actually contains. Try a hard coded value like `Guid.Parse("e68b2095-2d53-46a6-bca6-1e13f7bd2d26")`

Comment: @AluanHaddad still returns null

Comment: What mongo db driver are you using?

Comment: @AluanHaddad MongoDb.Driver 2.11.5

Comment: Hmm, I haven't used it recently, and don't have an instance running. I think you might want to declare the property as [`ObjectId`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/reference/bson/mapping/) instead of `Guid`. You might try converting them to strings and comparing them as a stopgap.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I thought setting the property as ObjectId but I would ending up with a tight couple between my Domain and my DBMS. Converting both sides with .ToString() during query returns a runtime error =/
I'm struggling with this over 2 days

Comment: have you tried
GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue is due the bson representation of the field which confuses some old .net driver.

using

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy));
```

should remedy

more info here:

https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-best-practices-uuid-data/

and here

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_GuidRepresentation.htm

Comment: Now I've got `Binary('VfsZGXKHh0u7sWo6JkPPWw==', 3)` is there anyway to easily query against this value outside .net? I'll still need to query database directly for debuging and metrics purpose

Comment: Also in this scenario I'll be forever tied to mongodb, I would like to use GUIDs to be free to migrate to another DBMS in the future

Comment: have you tried any configuration on Mongo side? it looks like configured to use ObjectID rather then UUIDs.. not really an expert though

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following? I have used the `BsonRepresentation` tag before, where the id will be stored as string in the database, for easier querying. Your entity class would become like below. Just add a using statement for `MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes`. Im using MongoDB version 2.9.2.

```
public class Game
{
    public Game(Guid id, string name, DateTime dateCreated, bool isActive)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        DateCreated = dateCreated;
        IsActive = isActive;
    }

    [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.String)]
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; private set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public bool IsActive { get; private set; } = true;
}
```